# Missing lines in a Python list converted to csv

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list (called 'empty_list') made of 2781 elements and each of the elements in the list is a list made of 51 strings.
For instance, element 2776 of the list looks like:

> ['213466', '010', '011', '011', '2', '', '', '', '8760', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

All other elements are similar.
However, when I try to export this list to a .csv file using:

```
out = csv.writer(open('h02_fin.csv','w'),delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
out.writerows(empty_list)
```

I find out that part of the element of empty_list indexed by 2776 (the list above) is missing in the .csv file.

And all the subsequent elements of the list are missing as well (i.e. elements 2777 to 2780 of empty_list).
Any idea where this might stem from knowing that the lenght is ok?

Comment: Can you test it with a smaller file containing a few lines surrounding line 2776, and still see the same result?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. Actually I think I found out how to solve this. The thing is that I had another csv file opened in my code at the same time. I just put a close statement for the old csv file before writing on the new csv file. Now it seems to work. Do you have any idea why it did something like this?